# Bracketed key value - limit OR foreach ... in OR?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Continuing my quest to convert .NET to Progress, I faced another challenge yesterday.

Our company bought time ago a .NET DLL to manage Excel document without the need to install Microsoft Excel. There is several functions that return a series of cells depending of the need.

The returned value is a class that implement IEnumerator interface in .NET.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to iterate trough the cells without getting the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Row or column index is invalid or out of required range
```

Is there a way to in Progress to validate if X is inside of the extent range?
OR
Is there a way to iterate trough the array without knowing the upper limit of the array?

Thank you!
Sebastien

--- temporary solution ---

```
/* declaration */
DEFINE VARIABLE oCell AS CLASS GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelCell NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oRange AS CLASS GemBox.Spreadsheet.CellRange NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

/* load excel file */
...

/* retrieve a series of cells */
ASSIGN oRange = oWorksheet:Cells:GetSubrangeAbsolute(1,1, 2,2).

/* first cell */
ASSIGN i = 0.
ASSIGN oCell = ?.
ASSIGN oCell = oRange:Item[i] NO-ERROR.

/* validate cell is in the range */
DO WHILE NOT oCell EQ ?:

    MESSAGE oCell:Value VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

    /* next cell */
    ASSIGN i = i + 1.
    ASSIGN oCell = ?.
    ASSIGN oCell = oRange:Item[i] NO-ERROR.
END.
```

Comment: The return value class is CellRange: http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Spreadsheet/Help/html/AllMembers_T_GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellRange.htm

Comment: I tried DISPLAY EXTENT(oRange). and it return 0.

Comment: There is no COUNT available in the class

Comment: The .NET version of the code was a FOR EACH Cell IN Range { ... }.  The upper limit was not needed.

Comment: I tried DISPLAY EXTENT(oRange:Item). and I got a compiler error: Only indeterminate array variables (defined with no numeral after EXTENT) are allowed as a parameters for the EXTENT statement. (14901)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access nor I can test this solution, but if it implements correctly the interface some solution like this one should work:

```
/* declaration */
DEFINE VARIABLE oCell AS CLASS GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelCell NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oRange AS CLASS GemBox.Spreadsheet.CellRange NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oEnumerator AS CLASS System.Collections.IEnumerator NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

/* load excel file */
...

/* retrieve a series of cells */
ASSIGN oRange = oWorksheet:Cells:GetSubrangeAbsolute(1,1, 2,2).

oEnumerator = oRange:getEnumerator().
DO WHILE oEnumerator:MoveNext():
   oCell = CAST(oEnumerator:current,"GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelCell").
END.
```

If it doesn't work exactly like this, at least it should point you in the correct direction to use it.

Comment: `ASSIGN oObject = oEnumerator:Current. /* SUCCESS */`
`ASSIGN oCell = oEnumerator:Current. /* FAIL */`

Comment: Cool! A step further! How does the CAST works in Progress? Like how can I cast the Object to a Cell in the assign? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the web page I'd infer that the # of cols =

```
oRange:LastColumnIndex - oRange:FirstColumnIndex
```

and the # of rows is

```
oRange:LastRowIndex - oRange:FirstRowIndex
```

I'd think using

```
 oCell = oRange:Item[Int32, Int32]
```

to get the item at the row, col position would work better instead of using a single element array element.

Comment: Thank you Tim! Unfortunately, Progress does not support multi dimensional arrays. I am hoping this will be supported in new version.

Comment: GetSubrange was used as an example for simplicity, there are other functions that can return cells by criteria like "by range name" that will not be necessary a rectangle selection.